Is this integral exactly $1/4$?
Consider the piecewise defined function:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{\frac{1}{\ln(1-x)}} & \text{if } 0<x < \frac{1}{2}, \\ \frac{1}{2} & \text{if } \frac{1}{2}< x < 1 - e^{-\frac{1}{\ln 2}}, \\ 1 - e^{\frac{1}{\ln(1-x)}} & \text{if } 1 - e^{-\frac{1}{\ln 2}} < x < 1 . \end{cases}$$
I want to find a closed form for:
$$ I=\int_0^1 f(x)~dx. $$
I started by writing this out in more detail:
$$I= \int_0^{1/2} e^{\frac{1}{\log(1-x)}} ~dx+\int_{1/2}^{1-e^{-\frac{1}{\log 2}}}\frac{1}{2}~dx+\int_{1-e^{-\frac{1}{\log 2}}}^1 1-e^{\frac{1}{\log(1-x)}} ~dx$$
A high precision numerical integration gives:
$$\boxed{I\approx{0.25000000000000020000}}$$

Is $I$ exactly $1/4$? If so, how do you arrive at this result analytically?

I already know that
$$ \int_0^1 e^{\frac{1}{\log(1-x)}}~dx=2K_1(2)$$
which is a modified Bessel function, so I think some Bessels must be canceling to get something exactly or very close to a rational.

Maybe symmetry of $e^\frac1{ln(1-x)}$ can be used

Plotting $f(x)=e^\frac1{\ln(1-x)}$ in red and $1-f(x)$ in blue,

one finds the red and blue areas under the respective graphs add up to a rectangle of area $af(a)$ meaning:
$$\int_0^af(x)dx+\int_{1-f(a)}^1(1-f(x))dx=af(a)$$

Alternatively, consider the inverse function of $f(x)=e^\frac1{\ln(1-x)}$:
$$x=e^\frac1{\ln(1-y)}\iff y=1-e^\frac1{\ln(x)}=1-f(1-x)$$
and therefore, shifting $x\to 1-x$, $1-f(x)=f^{-1}(1-x)$. Now using a generalization of the question and this result gives:
$$\int_0^af(x)dx+\int_{1-f(a)}^1(1-f(x))dx=\int_0^af(x)dx+\underbrace{\int_{1-f(a)}^1f^{-1}(1-x)dx}_{x\to1-x}=\int_0^af(x)dx+\int_0^{f(a)}f^{-1}(x)dx=af(a)$$
where $\int_0^af(x)dx+\int_0^{f(a)}f^{-1}(x)dx=af(a)$ by the integral of inverse functions theorem.

Either method shows that:
$$\boxed{\int_0^a e^\frac1{\ln(1-x)} dx+\int_{1-e^\frac1{\ln(1-a)}}^11-e^\frac1{\ln(1-x)}dx=a e^\frac1{\ln(1-a)}\\\mathop\implies^{a=\frac12}\int_0^\frac12 e^\frac1{\ln(1-x)}dx+\int_{1-e^{-\frac1{\ln 2}}}^1 1-e^\frac1{\ln(1-x)}dx-\frac12e^{-\frac1{\ln(2)}}=0}$$

After collecting terms of constant integrals, we wish to show that $$\frac1{2e^{1/\ln2}}+\left(\int_0^{1/2}+\int_{1-e^{-1/\ln2}}^1\right)e^{1/\ln(1-x)}\,dx=0.$$ Letting $u=1/\ln(1-x)$, this is equivalent to $$\frac1{2e^{1/\ln2}}+\left(\int_{-\infty}^{-1/\ln2}+\int_{-\ln2}^0\right)\frac{e^{u+1/u}}{u^2}\,du=0.$$ The substitution $v=1/u$ on the first integral only and variable replacement $u\rightarrow v$ on the second integral yield $$\frac1{2e^{1/\ln2}}+\int_{-\ln2}^0\left(1-\frac1{v^2}\right)e^{v+1/v}\,dv=0$$ but this is obvious since $1-1/v^2$ is the derivative of $v+1/v$.

Let $f(x)=e^{1/\ln(1-x)}$. Its domain of interest excludes $x=1$. We want to rewrite
$$\frac{1}{2\,e^{1/\ln 2}}
\;+\;
\int_{0}^{1/2} f(x)\,dx
\;+\;
\int_{1-e^{-1/\ln 2}}^{1} f(x)\,dx$$
as a sum of two integrals of the same integrand plus a constant. Define $w=\ln\!\bigl(1-x\bigr)$, so $x=1-e^w$ and $dx=-\,e^w\,dw$. Then $f(x)\,dx$ becomes $\bigl(e^{1/w}\bigr)\bigl(-e^w\bigr)dw=-\,e^{\,w+\tfrac{1}{w}}\,dw$. The part $x\in[0,1/2]$ maps $w$ from $0$ down to $\ln\tfrac12<0$, and the part $x\in[\,1-e^{-1/\ln 2},1]$ maps $w$ from $-\,\tfrac{1}{\ln 2}$ down to $-\infty$. Thus the total integral of $f$ over those two intervals becomes
$$
\int_{\,\ln(\tfrac12)}^{0} e^{\,w+\tfrac{1}{w}}\,dw
\;+\;
\int_{-\infty}^{-\tfrac{1}{\ln 2}} e^{\,w+\tfrac{1}{w}}\,dw.
$$
Combine them into a single range $\bigl(-\infty,0\bigr)$ excluding $\bigl(-\tfrac{1}{\ln 2},\,\ln\tfrac12\bigr)$. On each sub‐range, introduce $z=w+\tfrac{1}{w}$. Its derivative is $\tfrac{d}{dw}\bigl(w+\tfrac{1}{w}\bigr)=1-\tfrac{1}{w^2}$. Hence
$$
e^{\,w+\tfrac{1}{w}}
\;=\;
\frac{e^{\,z}}{\,1-\tfrac{1}{w^2}\,}
\;=\;
\frac{1}{\,1-\tfrac{1}{w^2}\,}\,\frac{d}{dw}\bigl(e^{\,w+\tfrac{1}{w}}\bigr).
$$
This converts each integral into boundary values of $e^{\,w+\tfrac{1}{w}}$, which vanish at $w\to 0^{-}$ and give precisely $\tfrac{1}{2}\,e^{-1/\ln 2}$ at $w=-\ln 2$. That $\tfrac{1}{2}\,e^{-1/\ln 2}$ appears with a negative sign, canceling the constant $1/\bigl(2\,e^{1/\ln 2}\bigr)$. The entire expression is therefore zero.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
